# Difference in formulas for combination

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Can someone please tell me, what is the difference between $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} $ and $\binom{n-1}{k-1} $?

Comment: $\dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ represents the number of ways to choose $k-1$ objects from a group or set containing $n+k-1$ objects. $\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$ represents the number of ways to choose $k-1$ objects from a group or set containing $n-1$ objects.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe this is obvious, I do not undersrand, when to use the first or  the second one

Comment: I do not understand your confusion. You say the definitions are obvious, but you do not understand when to use the first or second one. Please give an example of your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is the number of k-tuples of integers $(x_1,\dots, x_k)$ such that
$$
x_1+\dotsb+x_k=n\quad (x_i\geq 1)\tag{0}
$$
 for  all $1\leq i\leq n$.

On the other hand 
$
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}
$
is the number of k-tuples of integers $(x_1,\dotsb x_k)$ such that
$$
x_1+\dotsb+x_k=n\quad (x_i\geq 0)\tag{1}
$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Making the change of variables $y_i=x_i+1$ allows you to derive the number of solutions to $(1)$ from $(0)$ See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Thank you so much I was looking exactly for it.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*} {n+k-1}\choose {k-1} &=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!((n+k-1-(k-1))!)} \\ &=\frac{(n+1)\cdot \dots \cdot (n+k-1)}{(k-1)!}
\end{align*}
while 
\begin{align*} {n-1}\choose {k-1} &= \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \\ &=\frac{(n-k+1)\cdot \dots \cdot (n-1)}{(k-1)!} \end{align*}